# How do I prevent users to multi-tap (tap the screen with more than one finger at the same time) in a web page?

Tags: javascript, touch, touch-event, multi-touch

I created a JavaScript page to collect user's click/tap data. However, I don't want user to use more than one finger to tap on the screen. Currently, I have no way to filter out those multi clicks. I would like to totally dismiss the taps by more than one finger. What can I do? It's a web-page and I need things to be done by JavaScript.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

You could check the [`touches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent/touches) field in the event listener to see if more than one touch point was part of the touch event.

```js
document.addEventListener('touchstart', (ev) => {
  if (ev.touches.length > 1) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.stopPropagation();
    document.body.style.background = 'red';
    return false;
  }
  document.body.style.background = 'green';
  return true;
});
```